# Rails: Paperclip Not Saving Image to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have what should be a fairly simple setup for paperclip on my rails app.

My `products_controller.rb` is this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your product has been created!"
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
      redirect_to products_path
      flash[:notice] = "That product has been updated."
    else
      render :action => :edit
      flash[:alert] = "Something went terribly wrong there..."
    end
  end

  ...

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :active, :short_description, :weight, :box_length, :box_width, :box_depth, :product_image)
  end
end
```

My `products#edit` form (`products#new` doesn't work either, but it's the same form):

```
<%= form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <div class="form-inputs row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-9">
      <%= f.label "Product Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
      <%= f.label :price %>
      <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control", data: {autonumeric: true} %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <%= f.label "Product Description" %>
      <%= f.text_area :short_description, class: "form-control" %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <%= f.file_field :image, as: :file %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="form-group text-center col-xs-12">
       <p><%= f.check_box :active %> This is an active product.</p>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="row">
      <hr class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="text-center">Shipping Information</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <%= f.label "Product Length (in Inches)" %>
      <%= f.text_field :box_length, class: "form-control" %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <%= f.label "Product Width (in Inches)" %>
      <%= f.text_field :box_width, class: "form-control" %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <%= f.label "Product Depth (in Inches)" %>
      <%= f.text_field :box_depth, class: "form-control" %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
      <%= f.label "Product Weight (in Pounds)" %>
      <%= f.text_field :weight, class: "form-control" %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions text-center">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-manly" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my relevant routes:

resources :products

And finally the `product.rb` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  has_attached_file :product_image
  validates_attachment_content_type :product_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates_attachment_file_name :product_image, matches: [/png\z/, /jpe?g\z/]

  default_scope { where(active: true) }
end
```

And the `schema.rb` for the products table:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "price",                      precision: 12, scale: 3
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                          null: false
    t.string   "short_description"
    t.decimal  "weight"
    t.decimal  "box_length"
    t.decimal  "box_width"
    t.string   "box_depth"
    t.string   "product_image_file_name"
    t.string   "product_image_content_type"
    t.integer  "product_image_file_size"
    t.datetime "product_image_updated_at"
  end
```

I am getting no errors when I submit.  I have also tried both the `simple_form_for` and the `form_for` variations given in the Paperclip documentation.  I have double checked and ImageMagick is installed.  Can anyone see why it isn't saving?  When I check the console after trying to upload an image it just says `nil` for all four paperclip fields.

Comment: What's your model look like? Did you set up paperclip correctly? Did you have the proper migrations for your paperclip field in the model?

Comment: @PressingOnAlways, I added the schema and the model to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `:image` for `file_field` but your paperclip field is using **`product_image`**, change as follow to upload file

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
  <%= f.file_field :product_image, as: :file %>
</div> <!-- form group -->
```